# Why don't we use new keyword while converting int to bigInteger whereas we use new keyword in conversion from string to bigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

In the conversion from int to BigInteger, we write

```
int n = 100;
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
```

when we print bi, we get 100.
but, in the conversion from String to BigInteger, we write

```
String str = "100";
BigInteger biStr = new BigInteger(str);
```

`biStr` object uses the `new` keyword to store the value of the BigInteger value that is converted from a string, but where will the `bi` object store its BigInteger value that is converted from int.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at how `BigInteger.valueOf` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [BigInteger javadoc for valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf-long-):

> "This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers."